# Is Ubuntu Really This Much Slower Than Windows?

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu on my Acer Aspire One (2 gig memory, 113G disk available) from the www.ubuntu.com site using the Windows Installer option.  It is even slower than Windows.  I could make a sandwich in the time it takes to just open up Firefox, and Libre Office is no better.

I thought that Ubuntu is supposed to be a nice fast lightweight operating system.  What gives?

Comment: What graphics card do you have?  Have  you installed drivers for it?

Comment: "I thought that Ubuntu is supposed to be a nice fast lightweight operating system. What gives?" Well, it is. Runs much smoother than any other.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you have a problem with your PC. :)

Ubuntu will be a little bit slower if installed with Windows installer as it will be installed on a virtual drive and not an actual HDD partition. But never that slow.

Try running a disk defragmenter from your Windows installation before installing Ubuntu as your Hard Drive might be too fragmented that the virtual drive created for Ubuntu become fragmented all over your physical drive which will definatily make it very slow.

Something else, try to run Ubuntu on your system with a USB drive and check the difference.

Answer (score 0):

It can be really slow when you haven't installed the proper drivers. Else, it rocks on my 2 year old 140$ CPU, while windows lags quite a bit.